# How to do MultiLabel - MultiClass Classification in PyTorch? What loss will be required?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have to predict 5 classes `L1,L2,L3,L4,L5` in one model only. Values of each of these can range from `A-Z` so some valid outputs from model can be:

```
L1:A, L2:C, L3:D, L4:A, L5:E

L1:C, L2:A, L3:E, L4:D, L5:A

L1:B, L2:B, L3:C, L4:C, L5:E

L1:A, L2:E, L3:B, L4:D, L5:D
```

I don't want to make Multiple Models and want to do it all in one model only. One method can be to use `5` different Linear Layers with `5` neurons each. What will be the Loss for it? If I use `BCE` then it means I have to do the Binary and if I use `CrossEntropy`, it means I don't have independent classes. Let's say the model is like:

```
class MultiLabelClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_labels = 5, num_classes = 5):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        
        # Classification heads
        self.clf_heads = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.Linear(768, num_classes) for _ in range(num_labels)
        ])
        
    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        
        #BERT Encoding
        outputs = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        feature_vec = outputs.last_hidden_state
        
        #Pass through 5 different classifier heads each having 5 outputs
        logits = [clf(feature_vec) for clf in self.clf_heads]
        
        return logits
```

Now what should be the loss, metric here?

Answer (score -1):

Make the final layer a linear. Output 5 logits, one for each of your classes. Use BCE as the loss. It's smart enough to treat each of the 5 outputs independently.

Comment: But in the BCE loss, it would treat the first Level Predicting L1,L2,..L5 independently but what about the Internal 0-5 on the second Level? BCE means Binary Cross Entropy which means it is expecting a number -> Squash to give a probability between `0-1`. How would the `1-5` come in play?

Comment: Ah, I see. Make the model predict 130 outputs. It may be easier to then reshape that to (5,26). Have 5 categorical cross entropy loss functions attach to each group of 26.